# Routes com flask

Tags: python, aplicação-web, mvc, flask

Estou tentando separar as funções de suas rotas, criando apenas um arquivo para as rotas e um arquivo para cada função, porém quando tento chamar esse arquivo da função em rotas ele não o encontra:

routes.py :

```
from controllers.index import index

@app.route("/")
def indexRoute():
 return index()
```

index.py :

```
from flask import render_template
def index():
 return render_template('index.html')
```

**init**.py :

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_script import Manager
from flask_migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand
from flask_login import LoginManager

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

migrate = Migrate(app, db)

manager = Manager(app)
manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)

lm = LoginManager()
lm.init_app(app)

from core.models import tables
from core import routes
```

erro:

> (venv) C:\Users\Emerson
>   Carbonaro\Documents\GitHub\Nutrin\nutrin>run.py runserver Traceback
>   (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\Emerson
>   Carbonaro\Documents\GitHub\Nutrin\nutrin\run.py", line 1, in 
>       from core import app, manager   File "C:\Users\Emerson Carbonaro\Documents\GitHub\Nutrin\nutrin\core__init__.py", line 20,
>   in 
>       from core import routes   File "C:\Users\Emerson Carbonaro\Documents\GitHub\Nutrin\nutrin\core\routes.py", line 3, in
>   
>       from controllers.index import index ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'controllers'

- Caso esteja dando erro porque essa maneira de organização seja errada, avisem kk

Comment: O `controllers` está na mesma pasta que o `routes.py`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Já conseguir resolver o problema, a importação dos controllers devem ser feito desde o modulo principal.